# Rename column name in the whole database (all schemas)

Tags: mysql

I would like to rename a column currently named `deviceID` into a more [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) style `device_id`. Doing it into MySQL then in my code base with a sed `s/deviceID/device_id` seems to be the best solution.

So I wrote this helper:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', TABLE_SCHEMA, '`.`', TABLE_NAME,
            '` CHANGE COLUMN `', COLUMN_NAME, '` `device_id` ', 
            COLUMN_TYPE, IF(IS_NULLABLE = 'YES', ' NULL', ' NOT NULL'),
            IF (COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NULL, '', CONCAT('DEFAULT ', COLUMN_DEFAULT)), ';')
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'deviceID';
```

Then I can pipe the output into `mysql`.

Is there a simpler and safer solution?

Comment: Why do you think it's not safe? Because there is no user controlled input in this query.. Besides you can assume the VIEWS in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` database contain safe data..

Comment: Safe? Dunno, have you checked all your constraints,queries etc?

Comment: @RaymondNijland I think this is not safe because I have to rebuild all the column with the `COLUMN_TYPE`, `COLUMN_DEFAULT` and my script will fail if the column as an auto-increment or if it is a generated expression or a virtual column.

Comment: @P.Salmon I said `safe` I should have used `robust` or `reliable` instead.

Comment: You should delimit your schema and table names in backticks, in case they contain special characters or reserved words. For instance, what if one of the tables found is called `ORDER`?

Comment: @BillKarwin Correct I'll edit my question

Comment: Is your device_id column going to have a different data type, nullability, and default value in each table, or can you write that in a fixed way in your ALTER statement? In other words, why did you form the ALTER statement based on the column type and other options? Shouldn't it be the same in each table?

Comment: I see you edited your statement but you only put back-ticks around the column names which are sure to be safe anyway. You didn't put back-ticks around the schema name or table name, which are the ones that are unknown, so they're _not_ safe. You missed my point.

Comment: @BillKarwin Should be ok now

Comment: As with most coding tasks, the best way to be sure is to test it. Create a table `test.altertest` with one column of every data type and combination of column options you know occurs in your set of `deviceId` columns. Then produce your ALTER TABLE statements (limited to the `test` schema), and run them. Then check the tables to see that they worked.